# How to create a map with two lists (or vector) in clojure?

Tags: clojure

For example:

```
a = [:a :b :c]
b = [1 2 3]

(create-map a b) = {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}
```

What's the best way to implement create-map?

Comment: i implement create-map:
(defn to-map [ks vs]
  (into {} (map (fn [k v] [k v]) ks vs)))
Is there some function in library to do this or some better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [zipmap](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/zipmap):

```
(zipmap a b)

=> {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}
```